# Example of stochastic process AR$(1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, economics, time-series

An AR$(1)$ model is a stochastic process following the rule $$x_t = \alpha + \phi x_{t-1}+ \epsilon_t $$ with $|\phi| <1$, $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and $\epsilon_t$ a white noise.

Which is a real world example of this process? What does $\phi$ represent in that case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My impression is that a plain vanilla AR(1) process is seen more in theoretical work than in real-world work, and I wasn't able to find one in Google searches, but I managed to find this paper, ["Predicting solar radiation at high resolutions: A comparison of time series forecasts"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0038092X08002107) that found a seasonal version of an AR(1) process was useful for forecasting, or this paper, ["Predicting the Present with Google Trends"](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1475-4932.2012.00809.x/full). In a project for a class, I developed a version of the EM algorithm that clusters times series data when the data is viewed as being generated by different AR(1) processes, and it was able to find good-looking clusters of stock data based only on this assumption (you can read my paper [here](https://ntguardian.files.wordpress.com/2016/09/curtis1.pdf)).

But if you gave me an arbitrary time series process from the real world I'd have no reason to believe that it is an AR(1) process.

Comment: Thanks! What if we allow the process to be "almost" AR$(1)$. Are there examples then?